# Access the systems clipboard buffer from Python?

Tags: python

Is it possible to get the clipboard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>" buffer content with Python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get/set the clipboard via `bpy.context.window_manager.clipboard`

See: http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_release/bpy.types.WindowManager.html#bpy.types.WindowManager.clipboard

Comment: Thanks :) I already tried that command earlier and it didn't work... must have misspelled something :/ Anyway now it works :)